# Oracle JMS Message with user defined properties using PLSQL

Tags: plsql, queue, jms

I'm having problems trying to enqueue a message to a Single_Consumer QUEUE using PLSQL and I couldn't find any help neither on oracle's site, neither on stackoverflow.

I've been able to enqueue a message without user defined properties just fine but I can't seem to be able to enqueue the same message WITH a user defined property so that I can use 2 listeners with different message selectors.

The issue i'm encountering is that user defined properties should be put in the user_property field contained in dbms_aq.message_properties_t type.

The user_property field is a SYS.ANYDATA type of object and I need to put a pair (key,value).

I've tried this:

```
l_obj     t_my_type := t_my_type('tol', 'B');
l_anydata SYS.ANYDATA;
```

where t_my_type is defined as follow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_my_type AS OBJECT (
  g_val1 VARCHAR2(20),
  g_val2 VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Then I'm doing this:

```
l_anydata := SYS.ANYDATA.convertObject(l_obj);
v_message_properties.user_property := l_anydata;
```

And I'm enqueuing the message with this:

```
dbms_aq.enqueue(queue_name => 'queueName',enqueue_options => enqueue_options,message_properties => v_message_properties,payload => v_mv_payload,msgid => v_msg_id);
```

Problem is: the message_properties's field is populated with a "void" SYS.ANYDATA hence making the listener break apart.

Do anyone have tips for helping me solving this issue?

What I'm thinking is that I'm doing something wrong with the convert object from my complex object to anydata...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Oracle's support I've been told that AQJMS doesn't support this kind of implementation.
My need was resolved using Topics in the receiver-side.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before the dbms_aq.enqueue command:

```
v_mv_payload.set_string_property('tol','B');
```